# Can I carry a detached mounted gun with a car?

Tags: just-cause-2

I love mounted guns, specially when I detach them. My question is that is there any workaround to carry a detached mounted gun with a car?

Comment: I don't know if it'd work, but the first thing that comes to mind is: tethering the gun to the car.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No , as soon as you put the gun down its lost , there are no vehicles you can attach it to . you can however use the mounted guns that are already on jeeps and cars , you can't detach these though . most bases where you may need one usually have them either at the entrance or dotted around by sandbags